# how to override not valid email validation message mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, email

I am trying to override the default invalid mail message in model validation Error message

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Email", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation))]
```

and the resource text: `"{0}" is not a valid e-mail address`

I want it to look like:   `"[the input email]" is not valid email adress`

but i get:  `"Email" is not a valid email address`

Can i do it somehow trough model validation message?

EDIT:

I managed to simplify it a bit but still need help

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = string.Format(Resources.Validation.Validation.Email, ?what to put here?))]
```

Comment: Short answer is you can't. Attributes are metatdata and must be known at compile time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Validation Attribute,

Here is an example,

I have created a class with name `EmailAttribute` which inherits `ValidationAttribute`.

```
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            string email = value.ToString();

            if (Regex.IsMatch(email, @"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) // If it is a email address.
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success; // Success
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(email + " is not a Valid Email.");// here is the trick.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is required"); // required message.
        }
    }
```

And at the Model, you can use the it.

```
[Email]
public string Mail { get; set; }
```

**Result**,

[image]

Hope helps,

Comment: That will not give client side validation

Comment: @KirilKolev Did you add `ValidationMessageFor` at view?